# « Être fixé » (un incendie) : quel sens du verbe ?

Tags: sens, usage, synonymes

> Dans le sud-est, un incendie causé par un tir d’artillerie dans un
> important camp d’entraînement de l’armée française a brûlé environ 600
> hectares de végétation mais était sur le point d’être **fixé**. (AFP sur
> [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/2022-06-17/sud-ouest/la-france-et-l-espagne-frappees-par-de-tres-fortes-chaleurs.php), je souligne.)

De quel sens du verbe [*fixer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fixer) s'agit-il ici ; est-ce similaire à [*maîtriser*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%C3%AEtriser) ou est-ce plutôt comme « presque *éteint* » en contexte ; est-ce possible avec une « inondation », par exemple ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selon [cet article](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/faits-divers/incendie/incendies-qu-est-ce-qu-un-feu-fixe-maitrise-circonscrit-ou-noye_3604501.html) de France Info, citant le porte-parole de la Fédération nationale des sapeurs-pompiers de France : « un feu est **fixé** lorsque son axe de propagation est arrêté en tête de feu, c’est-à-dire dans l’axe principal du vent ; le feu “n’avance plus” mais les flammes peuvent rester vives et l’incendie “actif sur les côtés” ».

Comment: Merci, donc c'est un sens plus technique que ce que je pensais, même si ça me rappelle fixé à demeure ou immobile pour ainsi dire. Donc je ne m'attends pas nécessairement à ce que monsieur madame tout le monde dise ça spontanément. On me corrigera au besoin.

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa - En effet, je ne me souviens pas avoir entendu ce terme dans les médias avant cette année. D'habitude en entendait _maîtrisé_.